# Change only permissions and ownership of a directory

Tags: linux, permissions, gitlab

I tried to change default installation directory of gitlab, which resulted in changing permissions and ownership of all files. It is not starting up. I want to copy only permissions and ownership from some other instance. Is it possible?

Comment: Please add the exact command you used to the question.

Comment: cp -r /sourcefile /destination file

Comment: Please add it to the question. Not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# other instance
cd "$gitlab_root_default" 
getfacl --recursive . >/root/gitlab_permissions
# copy /root/gitlab_permissions to new system

# new system
cd "$gitlab_root_new" 
setfacl --restore=/root/gitlab_permissions
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I had some problem with redis but then I killed the process and restarted gitlab. I want to understand working of getfacl and setfacl. Could you please explain it.

Comment: @User860788 Read the man page or some articles on the web. If there are questions left then make a new question here.